# Catch MySqlException in VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

If I have this:

```
    Dim com As MySqlCommand
    Try
        com.CommandText = "insert into tabletest(id) values (1)"
        com.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MsgBox("Error")
    End Try
```

Connection is open, but the query throws an error (Table tabletest doesn't exist).

Is there any way, to get the query out of the exception in the catch?

This is only a sample of a query (and, of course, the catch-block). I have somewhere in the code a query, that runs into a timeout sometimes. And unfortunately I don't know which query causes the timeout. In debug mode, everything works fine.

Edit: because I don't know where the error occurs, I made in ApplicationEvents.vb:

```
    Private Sub MyApplication_UnhandledException(sender As Object, e As ApplicationServices.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) Handles Me.UnhandledException
```

And there I want to get the query like shown in the example above.

Comment: `ex.Message` should do it. (Sometimes the exact type is also needed, but it really depends if you want the message to work for users: but then even the message from the exception is unlikely to be meaningful.)

Comment: @Richard unfortunately not. I forced a timeout and got this from ex.Message: "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."

Comment: `ex.StackTrace` will give you more information.

Comment: Sorry misread as "more information". To get the query, if it is included, use a debugger to examine the properties of `ex` recursively (ie. look inside the properties where they have properties) so see if the command is referenced. Otherwise you'll need to pass the command instance, or at least the query text, yourself.

Comment: @Prescott Chartier yes, it does, but not in release mode. I tested all of the properties, but I didn't found one that delivers the `com.CommandText`.

Comment: I edited my question to make more clear what I want to do.

Comment: If you move `com.CommandText = "insert into tabletest(id) values (1)"` above the Try (it shouldn't crash since it's just a string) then I think you'll be able to use it in the Catch. Then you can see what query was executed when catching the error, and append that to your logs along with the exception (or whatever it is you're intending to do with the info).

Comment: try add Catch ex As MySqlException 
AND Catch ex2 As Exception, u sure if this exception is not system.timout ?

Comment: @Norbert At the moment, I catch `ex As Exception` and then I check, if `ex.InnerException` is MySqlException. And yes, I am sure, that it is the timeout from `MySqlCommand.CommandTimeOut`.

Comment: @ADyson please think, that I am catching the exception in ApplicationEvents!

Comment: @muffi It's not clear to me how that's relevant? Within your catch block, you can log details of your exception to the Windows EventLog (instead of just displaying a messagebox). You can add whatever you like to the event log, so at that point you could add some details as well about which query was run. Also the stack trace would tell you which methods it originated from, so you can work out which query it was based on that, too.

Comment: @ADyson you catched my problem. Where do I find the query to add it to the logfile?

Comment: in com.CommandText, like I exaplined. As I already suggested, if you move the line which declares that variable outside the Try block, then it will already be populated when the exception is caught, and so you can simply use the value of that variable as an input to your log message.

Comment: I don't have the MySqlCommand, because it is in another class - and I don't know where. Is it possible to get it out of the MySqlException or not in ApplicationEvents.vb? The Try...Catch in my posting is an example to throw an exception as i mentioned.

Comment: Eh? It's in the same class as your Try. Look: `Dim com As MySqlCommand
    Try
        com.CommandText = "insert into tabletest(id) values (1)"
        com.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MsgBox("Error")
    End Try` can become something like `Dim com As MySqlCommand
    com.CommandText = "insert into tabletest(id) values (1)"
    Try
        com.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MsgBox(com.CommandText)
    End Try`

Comment: I thought, it would be clear, if I write this EXAMPLE. In the real code there is no TRY...CATCH, because I don't know which command causes the timeout. This is the reason why I globally catch exceptions in ApplicationEvents.vb.

Comment: don't post code which isn't real then, it's meaningless and misleading. You said "a sample", I though you meant "an sample of one of the queries in my application". Anyway the stack trace of the exception should still tell you where in the code the query was triggered from at least, which hopefully gives you a clue which query was run. If not you'll have to modify the app to do more explicit logging, as per, ironically, your non-existent "sample".